# Необходимо распарсить данные средствами JSOUP

Tags: java, android, json, jsoup

```
<div id="page-item-viewonline" class="b-view-material">
<a href="/video/films/view/i4pFNH9WLbAdVfTbrfofDwY" class="b-button" rel="nofollow">
<span class="sliding"><b class="icon"></b>Смотреть онлайн</span>
```

Необходимо достать ссылку с тега `a` который лежит в теге `div` в котором есть класс `b-view-material`

Я могу достать все ссылки с тега `a` который лежит в теге `div`

```
Elements links = doc.select("div > a[href]");
            for (Element link : links) {
                list.add(String.format("a: <%s> (%s)", link.attr("abs:href"), link.text()));
            }
```

Можно ли указать еще и класс???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Читайте [документацию](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax):

```
Elements links = doc.select("div.b-view-material > a[href]");
```

Comment: Так он парсит `<a href="/video/films/view/i4ELKIEt6W8gAfsrQabgu4w" class="b-button" rel="nofollow"> <span class="sliding"><b class="icon"></b>Смотреть онлайн</span> </a>` Я добавил `.attr("href")` и парсит именно ссылку. Большое спасибо. Разобрался. С праздниками Вас!)